# How to archive the Eigen C++ 3.2.0 online document into a single mht?

Tags: c++, archive, eigen, chm

I find the online document of Eigen C++ template library is very useful in learning the algorithms and their usages: [Eigen 3.2.0 documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html) but is only available online or as separate html files.

How to combine all these documents into one `*.mht` or `*.chm` file so that all the `indices` and `cross-reference links` are all active for use?

Should the `unsupported` features be combined together?

Comment: It was generate by [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/), the doxygen can make `.chm` file. I think, you can download [the source](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/), and make the `.chm` by doxygen.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the doxygen, but failed. Do you have doxygen? would you please present a guide in more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build it, you can [download this file](http://alexchi.me/files/eigen/eigen.3.2.90.chm). *PS: The file has a `script error` when click the page.*

Also you can build it by yourself:

1. download and unzip the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/).
2. install [CMake](http://www.cmake.org).
3. install [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org).
4. install [HTML Help Workshop and Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138)
5. configure and generate the Doxyfile by [CMake](http://www.cmake.org).

   > - run the *cmake-gui.exe*
   > - set the source code directory to *Where is the source code*
   > - set a output directory to *Where to build the binaries*
   > - press *Configure* button
   > - press *Generate* button
   > - you can find the *Doxyfile* in [CMake Output Directory]\doc.
6. configure and generate CHM by [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) and [HTML Help Workshop and Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138).

   > - run the *doxywizard.exe*
   > - open the *Doxyfile*, generated by [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), in [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org).
   > - in *Expert* page, make *GENERATE_HTMLHELP* checked and set the *HHC_LOCATION* to the *hhc.exe* from HTML Help Workshop.
   > - in *Run* page, click *Run doxygen*
   > - at last, it will generate a chm file, named *index.chm* in [CMake Output Directory]\doc\html.

Good luck.

About `script error`, thank @LCFactorization. :)

> "I find the script error is only caused by internet explorer's security level; setting it to high solves the problem." from @LCFactorization.

Comment: Thank you very much! I downloaded the `chm` you compiled, and found similar error message I met: each time when I click an index link or cross-refernece link, there will be a `script error` message box

Comment: I find out it why there is `script error` message: the security level of my Internet Explorer is too low. After setting it to high security level, the problem solved. Thank you for kind help and your time! I tried to compile it myself and it usually takes one hour or so!! Additional question: How can I add the `unsupported module` to the same `chm`?

Comment: unsuported module document link is as: `http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/index.html`; in the `overview` section of the official Eigen document, there is such a link.

Comment: Yes, it has a `script error`. But I don't know how to fix it. Sorry for that, and add a tip in the answer.

Comment: 谢谢!I find the `script error` is only caused by internet explorer's `security level`; setting it to `high` solves the problem. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to download Eigen's sources, create a build directory and configure it with cmake. Then edit the build/doc/Doxyfile file, set GENERATE_HTMLHELP to YES and CHM_FILE to eigen.chm.
Then run make doc. You should find the chm file in build/doc/html.

Comment: I think it also need `Microsoft HTML Help Workshop` to compile .chm file.

Comment: Thank you @ggael @Alex! Actually I strictly followed all the details mentioned; but there is always something wrong with the obtained `.chm`: when I click some crossreference link, there will be error messages. that is the problem I cannot solve. Did you give it a try on the Eigen 3.2.0 source? what is wrong?